# How can I remove from memory the view controller I am exiting after I press a button?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Upon pressing a button in ViewController A, I want that view controller to completely be forgotten as I move to ViewController B. Here is my code to get to code B:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    MapViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapView"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Is there any way to stop the view controller that calls presentViewController from staying in memory? How can I dismiss it upon exit?

Comment: Don't do it , it's not how it works , you can't release a view controller that presenting another view controller. If in your app's flow you don't need view controller A after presenting view controller B than consider changing the flow so another view controller will present view controller A and/or B whatever is logical for your app.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I am not able to think of a scenario where you might need to get rid of the presenting viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

One Possible way to do it, is you have the following Setup.

Navigation Controller -> VC_A -> VC_B.

Here when you click on the button in VC_A, you ask the Navigation controller can remove VC_A from the navigation Stack & create and VC_B as the root view controller on the navigation stack and present it.

I still think this is not the right approach. If you could explain why you want to get rid of VCA, we might be able to think of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

dont remove from memory you can update its contents in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear